# Allow Spaces in HTML Text box

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

This is the Javascript & HTML code i have right now in my blog post.

```
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
<br />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function convertinput() {
    document.getElementById('output').value = "@@[0:[0:1: " + document.getElementById('first').value + "]]";
   document.getElementById('output').style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

```
<input id="first" maxLength=75 style="WIDTH: 300px;></input>
<br>
<input id="output" style="display:none;"></input>
<br>
<input type='button' onclick='convertinput()' value='convert'>
</div>
```

I can't insert a space in the input text box. 

What's the reason ? and what's the solution ?

Comment: Have you tried adding `type="text"` to your input?

Comment: `<input type="text" />` is the correct way to format such an input, plus you have a syntax error after `"WIDTH: 300px;>` - a missing close quote. I do not know why you cannot insert a space however. You should also chose whether to use ' or " quotes, not mix the two.

Comment: wats `dir="ltr"` and  `trbidi="on"` for?

Comment: The problem is apparently created by some JavaScript code that was not presented in the question and has been described as being part of obfuscated code. So you are effectively asking for others to debug some code that they have no access to.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing `"` in `style="WIDTH: 300px;>`

And another thing is `</input>` is not a tag closing. It has to be closed with this way:

```
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: is this right ?

<input type="text" id="first" maxLength=300 style="WIDTH: 300px;" />

Comment: but still i can't insert space

Comment: Can you show the HTML where we can try it out? Is there a public URL? *PS: Your blogger site looks innovative!* :)

Comment: Here's the link where i've posted it.

http://crackroachlab.blogspot.in/2012/10/function-convertinput-document.html

Btw thanks for your compliments on my personal blog.

Comment: Strange! I am able to copy and paste a `space` character but not give it. Need to check the JavaScript bindings.

Comment: All the JavaScript files are obfuscated. So, unable to check through. Remove all the JavaScripts and give a try?

Comment: but, javascripts are the one which i need the most here.

Comment: Yeah, in the trial and error way, remove one by one, and see which JavaScript you include, is making the space issue.

Comment: tried almost everything. nothing works. still space cannot be inserted. :(